# How to detect if function is called inside Rstudio or Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, rstudio

I am working on a 'high-level' function that requires user input. The way the function asks for input should be different, depending if it is called in an Rstudio session, Jupyter Notebook or terminal.

**How can one test for these environments?**

I have a really hard time searching for this issue. I have been thinking to use `interactive()` and `getOption("device")` to deduct where I am, but I was hoping there might be a more explicit way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio also always sets an environment variable `RSTUDIO`, among others.

In RStudio:

```
R> Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO")
[1] "1"
R>
```

Standard session:

```
R> Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO")
[1] ""
R>
```

So you can compare to `""`:

```
R> Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == ""
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to use `Sys.getenv()`! Jupyterhub also sets a few, though none is named this nicely. For starters I'll use your solution and add `any(grepl("JUPYTER",names(Sys.getenv())))` to it.

Comment: I suspected they would. It is a common pattern (and you'll see more from RStudio too) but I didn't have Jupyter up and it was already late :)

Answer (score 0):

### Partial answer:

To test for Rstudio one can use

```
.Platform$GUI
# [1] "RStudio"
```

which works both on Windows and Linux.

Unfortunately, for terminal and jupyterhub, this is both "X11" (on my linux machine). It could also be [a bunch of other things](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Platform.html), on other platforms.

However, this works, if we only consider the three expected cases:

`.Platform$GUI != "RStudio" & interactive() #TRUE for terminal`

`.Platform$GUI != "RStudio" & !interactive() #TRUE for Jupyter`